# Unit test file content creation before it being deleted

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following JAVA code:

```
@Override
public void myFunc(...) {
   String content = createFileContent(...);
   File f = createFile(content);
   uploadFile(f);
   deleteFile(f)
}
```

I want to test to file content, or the file itself (both can work), using unit test.
The file is deleted before the function ends.
What is the approach you would recommend on taking here? (I am using Mockito as mocking framework)

Comment: Do you want `myFunc()` only or other methods as well?

Comment: @sc0der myFunc only

Answer (score 0):

Spy the target test class and define the behavior and verify the calls of the methods, and if you want to assert the argument you can use `ArgumentCaptor`

```
public class TargetTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        // Arrange
        final String content = "content-file";
        final File file = new File();
        Target target = spy(target);
        doReturn(content).when(target).createFileContent();
        doReturn(file).when(target).createFile(content);
        doNothing().when(target).uploadFile(file);
        doNothing().when(target).deleteFile(file);

        // Act
        target.myFunc();

       // Assert
        verify(target).createFileContent();
        verify(target).createFile(content);
        verify(target).uploadFile(file);
        verify(target).deleteFile(file);
    }
}
```